# Angular: dynamic component

Tags: angular

I followed the Angular documentation to generate Components dynamically: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader.
This works fine, but now I would like to add a wrapper component around each dynamically generated component (later this wrapper should contain a toolbar). But I don't now how.

Wrapper component: still empty also the html

```
export class ComponentWraperComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

DynamicComponentBuilderComponent

```
export class DynamicComponentBuilderComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() elementConfigs: IElementConfig[];
  @ViewChild(DynamicComponentPlaceholderDirective, { static: true }) placeholder: DynamicComponentPlaceholderDirective;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private dynamicComponentService: DynamicComponentService) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    const viewContainerRef = this.placeholder.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();

    if (this.elementConfigs && this.elementConfigs.length > 0) {
      this.elementConfigs.forEach((config: IElementConfig) => {
        const componentToCreate: any = this.dynamicComponentService.resolveComponent(config);
        LoggingHelper.debug("DynamicComponentBuilderComponent.ngOnChanges(), interating over element configs. Building component " + config.type);

        // Wrapper
        const componentWraperComponentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ComponentWraperComponent);

        // Component
        const ComponentWraperComponent = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentToCreate);


**// Here I have both. The wrapper and component. But how can I add the component into the wrapper and than add the wrapper into the viewContainerRef?**


        const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume you put a child component into the "wrapper" via `<ng-content>`.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'wrapper-comp',
    template: '...toolbar... <ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class WraperComponent {}
```

then you could:

1. create the child component first
2. create the wrapper component with child on `ViewContainerRef`

for example:

```
const childFactory: ComponentFactory<ChildComponent> = factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
const childComp: ComponentRef<ChildComponent> = childFactory.create(this.injector);

const wrapperFactory: ComponentFactory<WraperComponent> = factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(WraperComponent);

const wrapperComp: ComponentRef<WraperComponent> = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(
    wrapperFactory,
    0,
    this.injector,
    [[
        childComp.location.nativeElement
    ]]
);
```